# javascript (jquery) not adding class

Tags: jquery, hash, addclass

```
if(hash=="ref=projects") {
    $("a#pj-title").addClass("selected-part");
    $.ajax({url:"/project.html",
        dataType:"html",
        beforeSend:function(){
            $(".loading").prepend('<div class="attention"><img src="ajax-loader.gif" /></div>')
        },
        success:function(a) {
            $("#rv-container").html(a)
        }
    })
}
```

Why doesn't the `addClass` method work? It doesn't seem to work within the `if` statement.

Comment: Is the if statement ever reached? Is the selector correct? We need more to go on.

Comment: Yes it is reached when the url is loaded and looks like this: example.com/dir/#ref=projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `hash` is from `window.location.hash`, then it will include a leading `#` so your code would need to be:

```
if (hash == "#ref-projects")
```

Also, `$("a#pj-title")` may be faster if it's `$("#pj-title")` since that lets jQuery use `document.getElementById()` as a shortcut and since there's only one object with a given ID anyway, you shouldn't need the `a` on the front anyway.